# Use keyword arguments to give a specific input

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I want to have something that has the following behaviour:

```
def plot(**kwargs):
    function(kwargs)
```

As input I want the following:

```
>>> plot(a = 1, b = 3, c = 3)
```

That uses it

```
function(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

I thought of something that might work, but it's not a clean code at all.

```
def plot(**kwargs):
   a = []
   for k, v in kwargs.items():
    a.append("%s = %s"%(k,v))
   inp = ", ".join(a)
   print inp
```

Now

```
>>> plot(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

Gives as output:

```
 a = 1, c = 3, b = 2
```

But then the following code doesn't work.

```
def plot(**kwargs):
   a = []
   for k, v in kwargs.items():
       a.append("%s = %s"%(k,v))
   inp = ", ".join(a)
   function(exec(inp))
```

**edit:**

```
def plot(**kwargs):
    function(**kwargs)
```

Seems to do the job...

Comment: Why not just call `function(**kwargs)`, i.e. unpack the dictionary back into keyword arguments?

Comment: Correct way is `exec('function({})'.format(inp))`, but why do want to do something like this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, that worked! Don't know why I didn't try that.